# Iteration issue with list/array

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm trying to iterate through a list to add pushpins to Bing maps. However I'm unable to add the pushpins once they are in the list. Can someone help me? thx

```
<div id="manualEntry">
    Your current location
    <input id="manualAddress" type="text" style="width: 500px" />
    <input id="getManualDirections" type="button" value="Get Directions" />
</div>
<div id="mapContainer" style="height: 500px">
    <div style="float: left">
        <div id="directionsMap" style="float: none; position: relative; width: 720px; height: 400px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="directionsList" style="float: left; overflow: auto; width: 250px; height: 400px">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var map = null;
        var directionsManager = null;
        var location = null;
        var STORE_LOCATION = "San Jose, CA";
        var storeLocations = [];


        //storelocations.add({ ClinicName: "Clin1", Lat: 49.276709, Long: -123.120543, Location: "west54th", Delay: 15, Doctors: [{ Doc1: "Dr. Br" }, { Doc2: "Dr. Stien" }] });
        //storelocations.add({ ClinicName: "Clin2", Lat: 49.273388, Long: -123.123165, Location: "west44th", Delay: 15, Doctors: [{ Doc1: "Dr. Yee" }] });


        showManualEntry();

        $("#askPermission").hide();
        loadMap();
        // Get the location
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 2000
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError, options);

        storelocations.add(["Clin1", 49.276709, -123.120543, "west54th", 15, ["Dr. Br", "Dr. Stien"]]);
        storelocations.add(["Clin2", 49.273388, -123.123165, "west44th", 15, ["Dr. Yee"]]);
        function loadMap() {
            // Initialize the map
            if (!map) {
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("directionsMap"),
                         { credentials: "AnytwRR35RZy6dxlt4BEAmhqyt-JljTEIk9rda4eUdszfA2O-TrWFEjDFkTrTeMp" });
               addPushPins()               
            }
        }

        function addPushPins() {
            for (var i = 0; i < storeLocations.length; i++) {
                var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(storeLocations[i, 1], storeLocations[i, 2]);
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, { icon: "/Content/Images/Plugins/Map/Markers/1min.png" });
                map.entities.push(pin);
            }

        }
        function showPosition(position) {

            if (position) {
                location = position.coords;
                map.setView({ zoom: 15, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(location.lattitude, location.longitude) })
            }
            if (!directionsManager) {
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: createDirectionsManager });
            }
            else {
                createDirectionsManager();
            }
        }

        function createDirectionsManager() {
            var displayMessage;
            if (!directionsManager) {
                directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
                displayMessage = 'Directions Module loaded\n';
                displayMessage += 'Directions Manager loaded';
            }
            directionsManager.resetDirections();
            directionsErrorEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', directionsError);
            directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);
            createDrivingRoute(location);
        }

        function directionsUpdated() {
            // Show Success message if required
        }
        function directionsError(args) {
            // Show Error message if required
        }

        function createDrivingRoute(coords) {
            if (!directionsManager) { createDirectionsManager(); }
            directionsManager.resetDirections();
            // Set Route Mode to driving 
            directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });
            var fromWayPoint = null;
            if (coords != null) {
                fromWayPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(
                                {
                                    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(coords.latitude, coords.longitude)
                                });
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(fromWayPoint);
            }
            else {
                fromWayPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: $("#manualAddress").val() });
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(fromWayPoint);
            }
            var toWayPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: STORE_LOCATION });
            directionsManager.addWaypoint(toWayPoint);
            // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
            directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsList') });
            directionsManager.calculateDirections();
        }


        function showManualEntry() {
            $("#manualEntry").show();
        }

        $("#getManualDirections").click(function () {
            loadMap();
            showPosition(null);
        });

        function positionError(position) {
            switch (position.code) {
                case 1:
                    showManualEntry();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    showManualEntry();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    showManualEntry();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had done some mistake that I will try to explain you.

When you add your pushpins to your Array, your code won't work for two reasons:
 You write storelocations instead of storeLocations and the method add don't exist in a javascript array. You have to use the push() method instead.

```
storeLocations.push(["Clin1", 49.276709, -123.120543, "west54th", 15, ["Dr. Br", "Dr. Stien"]]);
storeLocations.push(["Clin2", 49.273388, -123.123165, "west44th", 15, ["Dr. Yee"]]);
```

When you try to get you locations, try to do something like following, it works much better :

```
var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(storeLocations[i][ 1], storeLocations[i][ 2]);
```

Last but not least,
You can't call your addPushPins() function in your loadMap() function because you don't have any pushpins in your storeLocations Array. If you just call it after adding your storeLocations to the array, it will works like a charm.

```
storelocations.push(["Clin1", 49.276709, -123.120543, "west54th", 15, ["Dr. Br", "Dr. Stien"]]);
storelocations.push(["Clin2", 49.273388, -123.123165, "west44th", 15, ["Dr. Yee"]]);

    addPushPins();
```

Hope it help you